# Rails migration not doing anything?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I created the following migration:

```
class AddTokenToRegionTriggers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_column :region_triggers, :token, :string
    add_index :region_triggers, :token, unique: true
  end
end
```

There's a table called `region_triggers`. I tried running `rake db:migrate:up VERSION=123`, but it didn't do anything. The output is:

```
Enabling Bootsnap
Model files unchanged.
```

When I ran `rake db:migrate:redo VERSION=123`, it said `No indexes found on region_triggers with the options provided.`.

How do I make rails add the column and the index?

Comment: do you have `up` and `down` method in your migration ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you get the version number from?  Did you create the migration file using `rails g migration` ?

If so, it would have created the migration file with a version number prefixing the model name, so (for example)

```
rails g migration AddTokenToRegionTriggers
```

Would generate

```
20180501113025_add_token_to_region_triggers.rb
```

That initial numeric string is the version number.  To migrate up to that version, you can do

```
rake db:migrate:up VERSION=2018051113025
```

If you have no later migrations, you could just do...

```
rake db:migrate
```